# How to align a text outside of the legend in a fieldset

Tags: html, css

I want to align a text outside of a `legend` element, but I cannot figure out a way to calculate the width of the `legend`.

This example works exactly as I want, but it uses a hard-coded top and left dimensions. This breaks as soon as the width of the `legend` changes. Is there an easy way to do this? (Latest browsers are fine. No need to support old versions):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend style="border:3px solid red">
        Legend legend legend
        <span style="position:absolute; top:0; left:180px;">Aligned Text</span>
    </legend>
    text text text
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JS6dP/

[image: Example]

Comment: How do you mean "outside" ? Why would you do that? :)

Comment: Its hard to understand what you really want. Please elaborate.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I want to display "aligned text" as in the picture. I have to find the width of a legend to position aligned text next to it. cannot figure out to do it.

Comment: The width of a span will change with the number of characters placed inside of it i.e., "word" is a different width from "words".

Comment: I've been trying to solve this thing, and I've sort of succeeded. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/10/). If you remove the `float:left` from the 'legend legend legend' `span` using **developer tools** you would get the desired effect. But it doesn't work if you don't `float:left` the span to start with(see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/11/)). And I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Update: Both the fiddles work fine in Firefox. Chrome still has this problem though

Comment: Update 2: `display: inline-block` works, instead of float. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/13/). I still don't understand why chrome behaves oddly though

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `span` tags around the 'legend legend legend' text in the `legend` tag, and the other `position:absolute` span tag and `display:inline-block` them.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend style="">
        <span style="border:3px solid red; display:inline-block;">Legend legend legend</span>
        <span style=" display:inline-block;"><span style="position:absolute; top:0px; padding-left:5px; ">Aligned Text</span></span>
    </legend>
    text text text
</fieldset>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to assign a `position:relative` to your `legend` and `position:absolute` to your child `span`.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JS6dP/14/

**Remember**, the trick is to use a `right` value which is just higher than the `width` of this `span`.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend style="border:3px solid red">
        Legend legend legend legend
        <span class="legendText">Aligned Text</span>
    </legend>
    text text text
</fieldset>
```

CSS :

```
legend { position: relative; }
.legendText { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 92px;
    top: -16px;
    right: -96px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

since ever form tags are difficult to style and even more if you want it cross-browsers.

when you face a legend that needs a peticular style, best is to drop the legend for a hx tag to preserve semantic as much as possible.

From then, hx tags are easy to style and your fieldset should make no fuss about it :)

```
<fieldset>
    <h1 class="legend">
        Legend legend legend
        <span>Aligned Text</span>
    </h1>
    text text text
</fieldset>
```

```
fieldset {
  margin-top:1.25em;/* if no legend, increase margin-top*/
}
h1.legend {
  font-size:1em;
  display:table;/* to shrink on its content */
  margin-top:-1em;/* go up where legend stands usally */
  background:white;/* hide fieldset beneath */
  border:solid red;
}
.legend span {
  position:absolute;
  margin:-0.7em 0 0 0.5em;/* climb a little more */
  /* no coordonates needed, it shows where it is suppose too */
}
```

result : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wirLd