# fieldset>legend>span: Unusual Behaviour in chrome V32

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963532/how-to-align-a-text-outside-of-the-legend-in-a-fieldset) SO question and I noticed that Chrome renders the `fieldset` tag oddly if the legend contains a span inside it.

See these two fiddles:

1.[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/10/)

`<span style="border:3px solid red; float:left;">Legend legend legend</span>`

[image]

[image]

and

2.[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/11/)

`<span style="border:3px solid red;">Legend legend legend</span>`

[image]

The computed styles for all the tags, in both the cases, are identical, and both the fiddles behave properly in Firefox.

Comment: hello, giving some layout to span will help (span {display:inline-block;}, why float where text-align should be efficient ? relative/absolute for parent/child to control position inside parent ...

Comment: I know `inline-block` would work(that's how I solved the other question, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/JS6dP/13/)). I was just confused by the difference in the two cases, considering they have identical computed styles.

Comment: form tags are  pain to style cross-browsers and legend since ever as well , and once you find a trick/hack, it doesn't last after a few updates of browsers.Usually,it's given up to hX tag to replace <legend><legend>